# Folder disappeared after reboot in CentOS

Tags: centos

I am a Windows user new to CentOS 7.

I was running as root, and did some development work. I created a folder called 'docker' under '/dev'. During development I edited several files in Kwrite, and this session went of for several hours.

Then I rebooted the machine, whole '/dev/docker' folder is missing. And KWrite's recent folder list does not show my files. As if yesterday never happened :-).

Few months ago I faced same problem, and this happens randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/dev is a special file system for devices. It gets recreated and repopulated by the kernel when your computer starts up.

It should not be used for general files - documents, source code, music etc.

Also, you shouldn't be running as root. Create a user and keep your files in /home/username.
If you have to run as root, root's home directory is /root

Comment: Thank you. I will start using a folder /user/